# How to read sequenced declarations?

Tags: alloy

In appendix B: Alloy Language Reference of [Software Abstractions](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/book-chapters/alloy-language-reference.pdf) it is stated that

```
all x: X, y: Y | F
```

is short for

```
all x: X | all y: Y | F
```

but

```
one x: X, y: Y | F
```

is not short for

```
one x: X | one y: Y | F
```

I can't quite see clearly what is going on here and it occurs to me i am perhaps not reading this correctly at all..

my attempt would be "this is true if there is one instance, comprised of one x from X and one y from Y for which F is true".

Comment: Try looking at it on paper.

Comment: I get a strong feeling of missing something obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, `one x: X, y: Y | F` means "there is exactly one pair (x,y) in XxY s.t. F", while `one x: X | one y: Y | F` means "there is exactly one x in X s.t: there is exactly one y in Y s.t. F". In the latter case, the unique y s.t. F may depend on the given x.

To see what happens formally, you could translate `one` in terms of `all` and `some`; and then recast your example this way.